# Access to a two-dimensional array in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm learning about arrays in C, and I'm stumped on a homework question.

> The array access `a[j][k]` is equivalent to
>
> a) `((base_type*)a (j*row _ength) + k)`
> b) `*((base_type*)a (j*row_length) + k)`
> c) `*((base_type)a (j*row_length) + k)`
> d) `*((base_type)a (j*row_length))`
> e) None of these

Comment: Sounds like homework... what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: (e) None of these. (a) - (d) aren't syntactically correct or meaningful in C.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is : e) ,  None of these.

For better understanding read this : [Arrays and pointers in C](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/append-c.html)